# Is 012e2 octal or float?

Tags: c, type-conversion, decimal, octal

How should this be parsed in C language?

```
1000
```

(if octal `012` * 10 ^ 2)

or

```
1200
```

(if entire number as decimal)?

Comment: I don't know how the compiler parses it, but I parse it "someone is looking for trouble".

Comment: Where did that ugly constant appear? BTW, "octal or float" doesn't make much sense. Octal is a textual reprentation; `float` is a type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constant with an exponent is always floating-point.

There are no octal floating-point constants in C. (There are hexadecimal floating-point constants, but this isn't one of them).

So `012e2` is an unnecessarily confusing way to write `1200.0`.

(I can think of no good reason to write it this way, unless the intent is to be deliberately confusing.)

Comment: Regarding: _I can think of no good reason..._ Could be created by a code generation routine, and formatted that way for consistency with some template.  (maybe during the 1970s or 80s, when obfuscation was sport to some)

Comment: @ryyker: Perhaps there's a requirement for exactly 3 significant digits and no decimal point -- though `120e1` would have been just as <strike>good</strike> bad. (Yes, I know that particular markup doesn't work in comments.)

Answer (score 5):

`012e2` is a literal of type `double` and value is same as `1200.0`.

Floating constants are either decimal or hexadecimal floating constants. Decimal floating constants can start with any digit including `0`.

> (C99. 6.4.4.2 Floating constants)
>
> ```
> decimal-floating-constant:
>     fractional-constant exponent-partopt floating-suffixopt
>     digit-sequence exponent-part floating-suffixopt
>
> digit-sequence:
>     digit
>     digit-sequence digit
> ```

Comment: The fact number starts with `0` isn't mean to be octal?

Comment: @Jack: Only for integer constants (and as part of the syntax for character constants and string literals).

Comment: @Jack no floating constant are either decimal or hexadecimal